# Easy encryption program ubuntu for ubuntu 13.10

Tags: encryption

Hey i am searching for a program that can add a password too a folder with just right mouse click i am really lazy i already know there are lots of encryptions program but which one integrate well with the ubuntu interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eCryptfs will create a /Private folder where you can store your sensitive data, accessible with Nautilus: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory.

A (probably) more secure option is to create an encrypted drive with TrueCrypt: http://www.truecrypt.org.